# Java POI celltype

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a problem with java when I work on xlsx files, I know the document structure, but sometimes could be an error inside the cells.

For example in the column address could be a telephone number.

So getStringCellValue() throw an exception.

Since I can't know if there is an error, I thought to make a check of cell type, in this way I can handle the situation.

But I read that getCellType() is deprecate, and I don't found another solution.

Do you have any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: As far as I understand, the deprecation is just about the return type of `getCellType` (from int to an enum), see the javadoc: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getCellType()

Comment: I'm using POI 3.15, and the method is deprecated, in POI 4.0 probably will be replaced with enum return

Comment: Then use the `getCellTypeEnum() ` in your current code and as soon as ypou upgrade to poi 4,  just change  `getCellTypeEnum() ` to  `getCellType()`

Answer (score 0):

what about `.getValue()` and check with `instanceof`? if its an instance of string you can proceed otherwise you break

code looks like this `if (value instanceof String)` -> proceed

Comment: this is a good idea, but .getValue() doesn't exist for this kind of object

Comment: had in my mind that method existed